# IntEnum как поле структуры

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, enum

Допустим есть структура, заполняемая некой функцией. Одно из полей структуры на С описывается как перечисление (*enum*), само поле занимает четыре байта (представлено как *unsignd long*). Для примера:

```
LAUNCH_TYPE = IntEnum('LAUNCH_TYPE', (
   'LaunchAtBoot',
   'LaunchAtBootButStopAtErrorArised',
   'LaunchAtUserMode',
   'LaunchPending',
   'LaunchDisabled'
), start=0)

class OPTIMIZE_STATE(Structure):
   _fields_ = [
      ('Tag', c_ulong),
      ('Type', LAUNCH_TYPE),
      ('Info', c_void_p),
   ]
```

Однако интерпретатору непременно подавай C типы и потому LAUNCH_TYPE идет лесом. Не, я могу переопределить структуру как:

```
class OPTIMIZE_STATE(Structure):
   _fields_ = [
      ('Tag', c_ulong),
      ('Type', c_ulong),
      ('Info', c_void_p),
   ]
   @property
   def _Type(self):
      return LAUNCH_TYPE(self.Type).name if self.Type else None
```

Но это, мягко говоря, не совсем то. Суть задачи как раз и сводится, что в объявлении структуры должно быть перечисление. Таким образом возникает вопрос: Python поддерживает такую возможность или нет? Если да, как правильно реализовать код?

Comment: Пожалуйста, помимо метки python 3.x, добавляйте еще python просто.

Comment: "Но это, мягко говоря, не совсем то." - чем конкретно такое решение не подходит?